# WCF Web Service BLL for single ASP.NET app simplest approach

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, security, data-access-layer

What is the simplest effective approach for securing a WCF Web Service built to be a combined DAL/BLL consumed ONLY by a single small ASP.NET web app?

Background:

I am relatively a web development noob, especially when it comes to security.

Current DAL exists as a library in both the web app and an asmx web service, completely home-brewed in VS2003.  The authentication/token generation method is called via the web service, but everything else is called directly from the web app.  Our DBA is concerned that this is insecure and wants all database access to occur in a web service as well (I'm not in much of a position to question whether this concern/solution is valid in the first place, but if anyone can elaborate on why it is or isn't please do).

I am armed with VS2012 and this is my task.  My research has steered me to WCF, and I've already created a test web service, and a test web app that successfully consumes it.

Comment: What does the Business Logic return?  DataSets (strong or untyped), DTO objects (or maybe POCO objects), xml ?  Or what?

Comment: The current DAL has a single generic webmethod that accepts an OracleCommand (for the OracleParameters) and returns a DataSet.  I did not think this would work well over a web service, since serialized DataSets are so big) so I planned to also move the business logic to the web service too, so I can pass objects instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest discovering the difference between Type-Sharing and DataContract sharing.

But the quickest path is:

Use the NetDataContractSerializer for your DotNet objects that are coming "across the wire".
This is the "Type Sharing" serializer.  But it will only work when your client is only DotNet (which seems to be your case).

What I would do?

1. Create a Domain Library (that is **only** DTO objects)
2. Have the WCF IService(s) .. reference that library.  All the "contracts" need to accept scalars or objects in your DTO library.
3. Have a wrapper "services layer" (server side) that implements the IServices.  The code in here will be very "dumb".  Just pass the requests to your true business layer.  (The reason for this separation is so you can get to your business layer logic without going through WCF (think "unit tests").
4. Share your Domain Libary (DTO objects) dll with the client side.  (This depends on using NetDataContractSerializer, aka, using Type Sharing).

Once that is done.......you'll have "raw" WCF working.
Then you can apply your wcf security through configuration.

Here is a good walk through using certificate based security.

http://blog.mitchdenny.com/2007/09/06/using-certificate-based-authentication-and-protection-with-windows-communication-foundation-wcf/

Comment: Here is an older VS2005 example I did...back in da Day for my user group.   http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2007/10/18/wcf-with-interface-development/

Comment: Thank you, one quick question:  I was prepared to create a "domain library" but when I found that I was able to reference the types directly from the Web Service Reference, is there a reason not to do it this way (aside from code reuse of course):          if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            ServiceReference1.ProcessedClaim[] claims;
            claims = client.GetData(123, 456, (DateTime?)null, (DateTime?)null, "X");

Comment: If you want to stay in the 1.1 world of non generics.  ProcessedClaim[] claims << that is an array.  List<ProcessedClaim> claims is better.  public class ProcessedClaimCollection : List<ProcessedClaim> {} and ProcessedClaimCollection claims = ......  is best (IMHO).

Comment: "pay" the "create the domain library" price. you'll never regret it.  Having simple DTO, DTO_Collections will make your life easier in the end.

Comment: Actually I love generics, the web service is coded to return a ProcessClaimList : List<ProcessedClaim> i defined, but in the web app, it shows the return type as ProcessedClaim[].  Giving the collection type the [DataContract] attribute gave me an error.

Comment: That means you are not Type Sharing...and there some voodoo somewhere changing the Generic List to an old style array...........which is .. frustrating to deal with on the client side, IMHO.  you should check out my VS2005 example.  It has type sharing.

Comment: What your probably missing is that (while you are in your client app), when you add your "service reference", dotnot auto voodoo creates the proxy side code for you.  That is probably where the array items are coming from.

Comment: It was [CollectionDataContract] i was missing, found it in your code, thanks!  I've been bouncing between other projects and haven't yet delved too deeply.

Comment: That's why I do mini examples!  I forgot about CollectionDataContract myself........ :O